# How do you determine Pr(A|B) if the variables are independent?

Tags: probability

I've read that you can find the Probability of A given B by using the following formula:

Pr(AB) / Pr(A)

However, the variables are independent so you find Pr(AB) by using:

Pr(AB) = Pr(A) * PR(B)

Since you use the two formulas together, don't they cancel each other out, effectively making the first formula:

Pr(A|B) = Pr(B)

I'm a bit lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've read that you can find the Probability of A given B by using the
>   following formula:
>
> $$\frac{P(AB)}{P(A)}$$

Actually, the formula is $$\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$$ which means you should be able to easily see that $P(A|B)=P(A)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$
If variables are independent then you can write $P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(B)$. If we put this in above equation we would get 
$$P(A|B) = \frac {P(A) P(B)}{P(B)} = P(A)$$
And this equation $P(A|B) = P(A) $ clearly shows that probability of event A happening given B has already happened is exactly same as probability of happening of A only and that is what meant by independent events.